# In below code null pointer exception is thrown when we set the adapter into the spinner

Tags: android-widget

```
ArrayList<String> nameArray=new ArrayList<String>();
         do
        {
         nameArray.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")));
         System.out.println(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
         //set up the spinner

         Spinner spinner = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
         MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(nameArray);
         // apply the Adapter:
         spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

i have written above code to add string array into spinner.
but null pointer exception is thrown on last line.
i am not able to add string values to the spinner.
any one plz help me out of this.

Comment: i have created my own custom adapter thats name is Myadapter.

Answer (score 1):

`spinner` is probably null. Maybe you have no element with that specific id?

Comment: i have write spinner in xml file and use in .java file as below

Spinner spinner = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
then how it is null and values in spinner i have taken from array itself. while setting the adapter the exception will throw